# "TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable" in division list

Tags: python, object, integer, typeerror, iterable

I'm trying to make a program that searches through servers and finds a server with a player in it, the problem is the servers are split in to groups, like: **pages = (#servers / maxPlayers)**. I was able to get the number of servers through: `round(playing / maxPlayers)`, which **is** working but for some reason whenever I try using this: `for server in servers / round(maxPlayers):` it gives me "TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable". I have gone through so many of these same questions on here and none of them have helped me. Any help will be literally appreciated no joke I have been working on trying to fix this for like 30 minutes.

Comment: What are you trying to do with your loop? You can't loop through a number. Are you trying to iterate from 0 up to the value `servers / maxPlayers`?

Comment: yes i just started using that but now its giving: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 3 column 1 (char 4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should loop using:

```
for server in range(int(servers/round(maxPlayers))):
```

Comment: it gave this error: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 3 column 1 (char 4)